# What is the value of this repeated square root: $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt {3 \sqrt{4\cdots}}}}$

Tags: limits, recreational-mathematics

> Find the value of
>   $$\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt {3 \sqrt{4\sqrt{5\sqrt{6\cdots\sqrt{\infty}}}}}}}$$

What is the absolute value of the root in below question and what does it represent geometrically, I had a few approaches leading to possible values to approximation and know the answers, but I also need what it represents geometrically.

Comment: Please use more informative titles. And also don't misuse tags. This question has absolutely nothing to do with either (functional-analysis) or (complex-analysis).

Comment: this forum has a collaborative editing feature. If you don't want people to edit your posts, don't post here.

Comment: Well somehow, chilchin isn't only rude towards me. I'm relieved to hear that...

Comment: I removed many comments here too that were not at all constructive. chilchin, I see that you are very aggressive and rude in comments. This is simply not appropriate here.

Comment: @chilchin: what were your approaches to this problem?  There doesn't seem to be much room for maneuver to me.

Comment: This really is an interesting question, but the way it is presented just makes it unattractive.

Answer (score 11):

Let the limiting value of the above expression be $L$; then

$$\log{L} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log{k}}{2^k}$$

Comment: With $\log L \approx    0.507833922868439$. I had the same idea. WolframAlpha states that this series does converge.

Comment: yeah in my approaches and it approaches i get values and some of us have researched it but i think there is fundamental flaw there and i also believe infinite vlaues always approach to a finite value:)

Comment: @macydanim: it should be clear that the expression converges by comparison with $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{\epsilon}}{2^k}$$

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks for the information. You are right it should be clear.

Comment: @Ron: if the above expression is interpreted as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}}}$$ then it does in fact have a limiting value as you observed. (This is to say, under what I think of as the natural interpretation, you don't need the word "If" in your answer.)

Comment: ALL MY COMMENTS ARE DELETED HERE BY SOME ADMIN WHAT CAN I DO? @WILLIE no thew limit u suggested is not my question my question is aBSOLUTE

Comment: @willie: I agree, but I was hedging my bets and was not prepared to proved that the limit exists.

Comment: @chilchin: what do you mean by "absolute value" that I am not getting?  It should be clear that the posted expression is positive.  If you mean the explicit value, then anyone on this site should see that one obtains the value of $L$ by exponentiating the above result.

Comment: i didnot mean in that sense, absolute here being final and resolute my question posted here is only a part of what  is an analytically rational  and  complex function of more than 1 variable i thought if ppl could answer as well as some students and experts did on some other site i could have provided u ,should i say its sibling function and they magically in one approach tend to get already know very very famous ratio or constant ..but anyhow dont ignore this one one of the values suggested by what we got  also tend to have characteristics of a well known crop circle njoy ur time byeee :)))

Comment: @StevenGregory: The alleged duplicate was asked a year **after** this one.  Think again.

Comment: OK. I thought again. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898405/is-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-sqrt-4-ldots-algebraic-or-transcendental) for part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by Ron Gordon the logarithm of this is :
$$l= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log{k}}{2^k}$$
Consider the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) :
$$f(s):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1/2)^k}{k^s}=\operatorname{Li}_s\left(\frac 12\right)$$
then 
$$f'(s)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(k)}{2^k\;k^s}$$
so that the final answer may be written as $\ \boxed{\displaystyle e^{-\operatorname{Li}_{0'}\left(1/2\right)}}$ with the meaning : 
$e^{-\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac d{ds}\operatorname{Li}_s\left(1/2\right)}$

Comment: Nice(+1). I was just thinking whether I could interpret it as the derivative of some dirichlet-like series, but couldn't find one quickly. So this is an additional result. Cool...

Comment: Thanks @Gottfried ! You could write it too as derivative of the [Lerch zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) function. Unfortunately pari seems unable to evaluate non integer first terms (Wolfram Alpha is clearly better and returns the correct numerical value).

Answer (score 2):

The number in question is called [Somos's Quadratic Recurrence Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html), whose approximate value can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A112302). It is similar to the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html).