# Dividing $(a \times 10^{k} + b)^{2n} - (b\times 10^l + a)^{2n} $ by $a^2 - b^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[(a0000000…..000b)^2n - (b0000000…..000a)^2n] / (a^2 - b^2)is always divisible by **_ and equal to __** ? {Where a>b, n is an even positive integer; a, b, n > 0} ?

Comment: sorry  what is written here?

Comment: CAPITAL LETTERS COMMENT. DO YOU ENJOY THIS? NEITHER DO WE ENJOY THE TITLE.

Comment: @Asaf: I edited already.

Comment: @chilchin: What does it have to do with complex analysis?

Comment: u can assume l = k there or say there r 2n-2 zeroes in each term

Comment: ok no complex analysis for this question but see this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356977/mathematical-problem-functional-analysis-no-approxiamation-is-required

Comment: What is the connection between those?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell exactly what OP wants, but note that ...

$$x^n-y^n = \left(x-y\right)\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2} y + \cdots + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1}\right)$$

If we take

$$x := (a \cdot 10^m + b )^2 \qquad\qquad y := ( b \cdot 10^m + a )^2$$

and we consider just the first factor above, we have ...

$$\begin{align}
x-y &=\left(a \cdot 10^m + b \right)^2 - \left( b \cdot 10^m + a \right)^2 \\
&= \left( a^2 \cdot 10^{2m} + 2 a b \cdot 10^m + b^2 \right) - \left(b^2 \cdot 10^{2m} + 2 a b \cdot 10^{m} + a^2 \right) \\
&= \left(a^2-b^2\right)\left(10^{2m}-1\right)
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{(a \cdot 10^m + b )^{2n} - ( b \cdot 10^m + a )^{2n}}{a^2-b^2}= (10^{2m}-1)\cdot\text{stuff} = \underbrace{999\dots9}_{2m \; \text{"$9$"s}} \cdot \text{stuff}$$

Comment: good approach http://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue    close enough , i am satisfied but i would rather be happy if you post the absolute final answer :)

Comment: @chilchin: It's hard to post an *absolute final answer* when I'm not sure what the *absolute initial question* is. I've shown that the fraction is "always divisible by" $10^{2m}-1$; what else do you want? (The exact nature of "stuff" should be unimportant.)

Comment: dude i said u can assume l = k there or say there r 2n-2 zeroes in each term  there is a specific answer anyways http://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue i am leaving this site for bad governance njoy ur time here byee tc :)

Comment: @chilchin: Dude, I used "$m$" in place of both "$k$" and "$l$", which amounts to assuming that those values are equal. :)

Comment: yes right blue ...you will get a value in terms of a and b nevertheless its close and good try this question njoy bye  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356977/mathematical-problem-functional-analysis-no-approxiamation-is-required